# How to get a JavaScript array in the Python Pyramid framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, pyramid

I'm trying to build a web app which has the following functionality: At a certain point the user will be able to click a button to add a "box" (with 2 input fields) to his page. Every user can add multiple "boxes" so 1 user might have 2 on his page, another my have 5. I'm using jquery to do this and my logic is this:

- user clicks on the "add" button
- a html element gets appended to an empty array as a string
- I send this array to a database
- when the user comes back, I retrieve the array from the DB and add it in jquery again

Now I've managed to do the first 2 points (easiest =D) but I'm stuck at the next 2.

I'm using the Pyramid framework for this app and I thought there should be a way to get that array in Pyramid so I can send it to the database but I can't figure it out.

Could you please point me to some documentation, or something else from which I could learn how to do this?

HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  

<head>
    <link type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='add'></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The CSS is this:

```
.add {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 30%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20%;
    position: relative;
}

.room {
    height: 150px;
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    position:relative;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and the JQuery code:

```
var roomlist = new Array()

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.add').click(function(){
        roomlist.push('<div class="room"></div>')
        $('.add').before(roomlist[roomlist.length -1]);
        $('.add').css("margin-top","1%");
    });
});
```

Comment: Bogdan, you definitely can do this. However, please show your current jQuery, html, and python code.

Comment: @Raj Unfortunately, at the moment, I don't have any Python code since I'm still learning Pyramid. 
My issue is that I can't tell (from what I've read so far) what method/technology I can use to get "roomlist" from the static js file and add it as a variable in pyramid.
My approach is that I think about the design, find out what issues I might encounter, learn the tools to fix them ... write the actual code

Comment: Is this what you're looking to happen on the *client-side* (meaning in the browser for the user)? http://jsfiddle.net/K2EzP/

Comment: @Raj yup that's it... Now I'm just thinking how to store the array in a database

Comment: I found something regarding JSON renderers in the Pyramid documentation... I'll check from there and post if I manage do do it

Comment: This is how you send the array to the server: http://jsfiddle.net/K2EzP/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ... could you please detail more on why you chose "/echo/json/" as the url path?

Comment: Click on "Ajax Requests" on the left side of the jsfiddle page. It says to send ajax requests to jsfiddle's server use that address (because jsfiddle's server is accepting ajax requests at that address). If you sent it to a different address, it would throw an error because jsfiddle.net isn't expecting incoming ajax requests from the browser/client at that location. ~~ On your own app and server, you'll be using the route_url/address of the `view` you set up to accept the array you're sending from the client.

Answer (score 0):

In python pyramid you will get json render you can do it very easily. In pyramid you can work with GET, PUT, POST and DELETE method for restful web service.
By using GET method you can get your list in jquery and use POST method for saving your list in database.

[Ajax Development With JSON Renderers](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/json.html)

Example for GET, PUT and POST method

```
@view_defaults(route_name='myapi', renderer='json')
class GroupView(object):
   def __init__(self, request):
      self.request = request

   @view_config(request_method='GET')
   def get(self):
     # return information about the list or objest

   @view_config(request_method='PUT')
   def put(self):
      # update list or object

   @view_config(request_method='POST')
   def post(self):
      # Create new list or object
```